# JPA How to filter ManyToMany relationship

Tags: collections, annotations, many-to-many, jpa-2.0, predicate

I try to figure out how to filter this relationship:

```
EntityA{

   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
   Collection<Role> role;
}

User{

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
    Collection<Role> role;
}
```

What I try to achieve is something like an RBAC. 
The EntityA should be accessible by certain (multiple) roles.
A user has certain (multiple) roles assigned as well.

How can I return only the EntityA rows for a certain user? Meaning all EntityA rows that have the same roles assigned as the User?

This would mean to return only the values that match in the two collections (roles from EntityA that match roles from User). Is that possible with a Predicate ?